# How to generate data base with Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I start with doctrine and want to create a db or php class from table with doctrine.
First i try create db. My bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
 use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

 require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
 require_once "src/BugRepository.php";

 $isDevMode = true;
 $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);

 $conn = array(
  'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
  'user' => 'postgres',
  'password' => '123456', 
  'host' => 'localhost', 
  'dbname' =>'testdata',
 );

 $entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

and i do:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine doctrine:database:create
```

my output:

```
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../doctrine/orm/bin"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/doctrine"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

But db `testdata`not created.
Same with creating php class from table:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine doctrine:mapping:import YourAppBundle yml --filter="bugs"
```

But yml file not created.
Whats can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also a bin folder in vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/ you can use this one like this

php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

make sure you have root folder and a cli-config.php file is present in root folder.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doctrine-user/_ph183Kh-5o/_P_coljB-dcJ